# How to solve this static mechanics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, statics

I'm trying to recall how to solve some simple static mechanics problems, and found one on youtube that was solved in a way but I remember solving it in another way (more or less it is the same, but I'm more used to the "sum of vectors" method). So, here is the problem and my solution, but my result is not the same and would like to know if anyone could check where my error is:

[image]

It seems from the youtube video that correct result is:

```
T2 = 246.1 N
T3 = 445.8 N
```

But I'm getting:

```
T2 = 200.76 N
T3 = 363.9 N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your same result.

Write the equilibrium of the point coloured in yellow. The projections of the equilibrium of forces along $x$ and $y$ directions read:

$x: -T_3 \cos(60°) + T_2 \cos(25°) = 0$
$y:  T_3 \sin(60°) + T_2 \sin(25°) - W = 0$

This is a linear system, you can easily solve, to get your same result.

Comment: Plugging in the formula in the box on right, I get 200.76 and 363.91. Also using the formula of basics the same answer.

Comment: I was getting crazy with that one :/. Did not notice they guy in the youtube video wrongly used 490 instead of 400 N. Thanks for the confirmation!